# Dynamic query returns "Query returned successfully" and not the dataset?

Tags: postgresql

Very elementary question, but how does one go about returning the resultset of a dynamically created query, without declaring the tables return columns?

I have tried many things but with no luck.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    query_text text;
BEGIN
    -- Build the dynamic SQL query
    query_text :=
    '
    CREATE TEMP TABLE result_table AS
    SELECT
        obj->>''objectsourceeid'' AS datatag,
        MAX(CASE WHEN (obj->>''objectclasstitle'') = ''area'' THEN obj->>''objectclassid'' END) AS area_objectclasstitle,
        MAX(CASE WHEN (obj->>''objectclasstitle'') = ''area'' THEN (obj->>''objectinstanceproperty'')::JSONB->>''objectinstanceproperty'' END) AS area_objectinstance
    FROM 
        TEMP_JSON_DATA, 
        jsonb_array_elements(data::JSONB) AS obj
    GROUP BY
        datatag;
        SELECT * FROM result_table;
        
    DROP TABLE result_table;
    ';

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query and store the result in the result_record variable
    EXECUTE query_text;
END $$;
```

Here is some temp data elements. I use JSONB.

````
CREATE TEMP TABLE TEMP_JSON_DATA (DATA JSONB);-- Insert the JSON data into the temporary table
 
INSERT INTO TEMP_JSON_DATA (DATA)
 
VALUES ('[
    {
        "Lvl": 1,
        "objectclassid": "8DEE7GB6-35E1-43DC-8A53-900A30ECCD4A",
        "objectclasstitle": "Root",
        "objectinstance": "2465f43ff41e1aeefa21b15073224e191fda5907",
        "objectinstanceproperty": {
            "objectinstanceproperty": ""
        },
        "objectsourceeid": "P000_P1_TOT"
    },
    {
        "Lvl": 2,
        "objectclassid": "8B53E756-481E-4464-B1FE-28A96B10446C",
        "objectclasstitle": "area",
        "objectinstance": "873365aef4da0a5f2e7764528ddc02453e5a7bda",
        "objectinstanceproperty": {
            "objectinstanceproperty": "P"
        },
        "objectsourceeid": "P000_P1_TOT"
    }
    ] '::JSONB);
    ```
Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to create a function. If you don't need a permanent function, you can create a temporary one that will be removed when you disconnect:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.gimmethesedata()
   RETURNS TABLE (datatag text, area_objectclasstitle text, area_objectinstance text)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   ...
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query_text;
END;$$;
```

You call it with the schema name:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_temp.gimmethesedata();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It works - Is it possible to wrap it in a stored procedure and use stored procedure parameters as return table arguments?

Comment: (maybe i am switching arguments and parameters around)

Comment: What is a stored procedure?

Comment: Maybe it is just called Procedures in Postgres. What I am looking for is a way to parameterize RETURNS TABLE () column list and type.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The result set must be fixed at the time you define the function. The only escape is to `RETURN SETOF record`, but then you have to specify the result set structure in the query that calls the function.